# aws firehose lambda function invocation gives wrong output strcuture format

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

When  i insert a data object to aws firhose stream using a put operation it works fine .As lambda function is enabled on my firehose stream .hence a lambda function is invoked but  gives me a output structure response error :

```
"errorMessage":"Invalid output structure: Please check your function and make sure the processed records contain valid result status of Dropped, Ok, or ProcessingFailed."
```

so now i have created my lambda function like this way  to make the correct output strcuture :

```
import base64
import json

print('Loading function')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    output=[]
    print('event'+str(event))
    for record in event['records']:
        payload = base64.b64decode(record['data'])
        print('payload'+str(payload))
        payload=base64.b64encode(payload)
        output_record={
            'recordId':record['recordId'],
            'result': 'Ok',
             'data':  base64.b64encode(json.dumps('hello'))
        }
    output.append(output_record)
    return { 'records': output }
```

Now i am getting the follwing eror on encoding the 'data' field as

```
"errorMessage": "a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'",
```

and if i change the 'hello' to bytes  like b'hello' then i get the following error  :

```
 "errorMessage": "Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable",
```

Comment: Solution 'data': base64.b64encode('hello'.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8').The processed/updated  data can be passed as string in place of word 'hello' to eoncode data while sending data back to Queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import json
import base64
import gzip
import io
import zlib

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    output = []

```
for record in event['records']:
    payload = base64.b64decode(record['data']).decode('utf-8')
    output_record = {
        'recordId': record['recordId'],
        'result': 'Ok',
        'data': base64.b64encode(payload.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
    }
    output.append(output_record)

return {'records': output}
```